# Getting text from EditText without a button

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext

In my app i create an EditText dynamically when a CheckBox is not checked and i want to get the text the user writes in it. The problem is that i don't know where to write the getText().toString(). I have debugged this and i see that when the EditText is created the getText().toString() is executed immediately and returns always "" . I have also tried the focusChange in the EditText but without any success. Any help is appreciated!

```
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(getPx(100) , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0 ,0 ,getPx(100) ,0);
        tr.addView(editText);
        date = editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: use `textWatcher`

Comment: i have tried this too. But when i write the code in afterTextChanged , the code is executed when i write only a one number. I need it to be executed when the user writes a hole date.

Comment: how do you know if the user written whole date? how you determine it?

Comment: Yeah thats really an issue. I guess when they click done in the keyboard, or when they press the back button

Comment: So looks like you don't know, right? This way best is to use button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
         editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(isValidDate()) {
                   date = s.toString();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    ...

    private boolean isValidDate() {
       // implement your logic here
    }
```

Comment: yes i did. But the code in afterTextChanged is executed when the user writes only a single character. I want him to write a date and then get it

Comment: You can check in onTextChanged if the string is a valid date. If it is, you update the variable.

Answer (score 0):

So you dont want to take text when user inputs.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String typedStringIs=s.toString();
            //Here your code . It is dynamaclly changing . if anything you write will be here
            }
        });
```

Comment: so here the typedStringIs is the text that the user writes?